# How to make a tristate checkbox in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, checkbox

Situation: I have a GUI with a list of objects, and their properties. One of these properties is a boolean, which is a good fit for a checkbox.

The list allows multiple objects to be simultaneously selected, to change the properties in batch. When selecting multiple objects, I update the properties list to display the common ones.

Everything works well if the objects have the same value set for the boolean property, but I would like to display a checkbox in a third state: "undefined", "other" when this property is different.

So far, I haven't been able to create a tristate checkbox. Is it possible somehow?

The checkbox is created with a variant of:

```
myCheckbox = uicontrol(figureHandle,...
        'Style','CheckBox',...
        'String','Boolean Property');
set(myCheckbox, 'Value', 1); % Checks the checkbox
set(myCheckbox, 'Value', 0); % Unchecks the checkbox
set(myCheckbox, 'Value', 2); % Expected: tristate. Gets: warning
```

When trying to set the checkbox to a third state, I get a warning message that the `value` be equal to either the `Max` or `Min` value. Those must be separated by a difference of `1`. So, is there a way to display a tristate checkbox in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, which is a shame. There is however some [undocumented Matlab functionality to do so](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/246437).
More specifically, the Java user interface supports tristate checkboxes, and it is possible to display such elements by using them directly.

It is not a perfect solution, however, as this UI element won't have the standard set of properties other Matlab UI elements have, and as such, the functions `get`, `set`, etc... won't be able to affect its state.

The undocumentedmatlab website [points out](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tri-state-checkbox) that the `findobj` script can be used to handle this use case more easily. This however requires an extra dependency (`findobj` itself).

---

The sollution I settled on was to change the appearance of the checkbox to the one of a radio button. This doesn't look perfect, and is a hacky solution, but it fulfills its role as a visual cue that the state isn't a normal one, especially since I do not have any other radio buttons in the user interface.

```
set(myCheckbox, 'Style', 'RadioButton', 'Value', 1); % Setting the value to 1 is cosmetic
```

The advantages here is that it retains the existing callback, provides an obvious visual clue, is compatible with the Matlab methods and properties, and is very simple to implement (the radiobutton shares most properties with the checkbox, except for its shape, obviously).

The main inconvenient is that we cannot rely on the knowledge of the user to determine that the radio button is a tristate checkbox, since it is not a common convention. This can however be solved by educating the user (with a tooltip, for example). As this tool is going to be used by a limited number of people, this is an acceptable compromise for me.

The second drawback, and perhaps less obvious, is that the UI thread doesn't handle the state change for us anymore. We must instead change the `Style` property of the object in the callback. I still consider the extra code to be good tradeoff, since the alternative requires some (more?) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to set 'Enable' property to 'off', or make it invisible if it applies, when the 'Value' is not 0 or 1. Then in callback, you will need to read this property before you read its 'Value'.

```
val = 1; % it may be other, like 2
myCheckbox = uicontrol(gcf, 'Style','CheckBox',  String','Boolean Property');
if val==1 || val==0
    set(myCheckbox, 'Enable', 'on'); % make sure enabled
    % set(myCheckbox, 'Visible', 'on'); % or make it visible
    set(myCheckbox, 'Value', val); % Check or uncheck
else
    % set(myCheckbox, 'Value', 0); % uncheck it optionally
    set(myCheckbox, 'Enable', 'off'); % disabled
    % set(myCheckbox, 'Visible', 'off'); % invisible
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, this solution won't do, since it disables the callback as well, and I still want the user to be able to force the property for every selected element at once. If it was only for display, though, that could work.